# What happens in an UPDATE statement in which the updated table isn't mentioned in the FROM/JOIN clauses?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I intended to run the following `UPDATE` statement on a SQL Server database table:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET COL_1=B.COL_1
FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
   ON A.KEY_1=B.KEY_1
WHERE B.COL_2 IS NOT NULL
  AND A.COL_1=91216599
```

By mistake, I ran the following statement instead:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET COL_1=B.COL_1
FROM TABLE_A_COPY A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
   ON A.KEY_1=B.KEY_1
WHERE B.COL_2 is not NULL
  AND A.COL_1=91216599
```

Notice that in this second statement (wrong one), the `FROM` clause specifies table `TABLE_A_COPY` instead of `TABLE_A`. Both tables have exactly the same schema (i.e., same columns) and the same data (before any `UPDATE` is executed, that is).

Both `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_A_COPY` have about 100 million records and the update affects about 500,000 records. The second statement (the wrong one) runs for several hours and fails while the 1st statement (the correct one) runs for 40 seconds and succeeds.

Clearly, both statements are syntactically correct, but I am not sure what exactly I asked SQL Server to do with the first statement.

My questions are:

1. **What SQL Server was trying to do in the second statement?** With my mistake I didn't specify the linkage between records from `TABLE_A` to `TABLE_A_COPY`, so was it trying to do a CROSS JOIN between the two, and then update each record in `TABLE_A` a gazillion times?
2. If it isn't too broad a question to ask, what would be a valid scenario for such an `UPDATE` statement in which the table being updated is not mentioned in the `FROM/JOIN` clauses. Why would anyone do that? Why would SQL Server even allow that?

---

<sup>I did try searching for an answer to my questions, but Google seems to think I'm asking about `UPDATE FROM` syntax.</sup>

Comment: My guess would be that you got a Cartesean product of `TABLE_A` and the join between `TABLE_A_COPY` and `TABLE_B`. That would certainly explain why it would take so long...

Comment: The second mistake is the correct one?

Comment: @Ricardo Which statement is correct? Your question (first/second and incorrect/correct one) does not make sense for me. Could you edit your question

Comment: The **first statement** is the correct one. I'll edit it and clarify.

Comment: @Ricardo Read your post `**The first statement (the incorrect one)** runs for several hours and fails while the 2nd statement (the right one) runs for 40 seconds and succeeds.`

Comment: @lad2025 - Right! Sorry - I mixed up both statements in that sentence. It's corrected now.

Comment: @Frisbee - sorry, my mistake. I've corrected the confusing sentence.

Comment: @Ricardo For me it is similiar case as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385665/how-is-this-script-updating-table-when-using-left-joins/32386372#32386372 and [`Let's deprecate UPDATE FROM!`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2008/03/10/lets-deprecate-update-from.aspx)

Comment: @Ricardo And answer for second [Deprecate UPDATE FROM and DELETE FROM](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/332437/deprecate-update-from-and-delete-from)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There is no connection between `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_A_COPY` so you will get `CROSS JOIN` and massive update the same row. Result can be non-deterministic if parallel execution is involed:

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379657)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE_A(KEY_1 INT PRIMARY KEY,COL_1 INT);

CREATE TABLE #TABLE_A_COPY(KEY_1 INT PRIMARY KEY,COL_1 INT);

CREATE TABLE #TABLE_B(KEY_1 INT PRIMARY KEY, COL_1 INT, COL_2 INT);

INSERT INTO #TABLE_A VALUES (1,91216599),(2,91216599),(3,91216599),
                             (4,91216599),(5,91216599),(6,6);

INSERT INTO #TABLE_A_COPY VALUES (1,91216599),(2,91216599),(3,91216599),
                                 (4,91216599),(5,91216599),(6,6);    

INSERT INTO #TABLE_B VALUES (1,10,10),(2,20,20), (3,30,30);

/*
UPDATE #TABLE_A
SET COL_1=B.COL_1
--SELECT *
FROM #TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN #TABLE_B B
   ON A.KEY_1=B.KEY_1
WHERE B.COL_2 IS NOT NULL
  AND A.COL_1=91216599;
*/

UPDATE #TABLE_A
SET COL_1=B.COL_1
FROM #TABLE_A_COPY A
INNER JOIN #TABLE_B B
   ON A.KEY_1=B.KEY_1
WHERE B.COL_2 is not NULL
  AND A.COL_1=91216599

SELECT *
FROM #TABLE_A;
```

Check in above code how `TABLE_A` record with `KEY_1 = 6` changed.

2)
SQL Server `UPDATE FROM/DELETE FROM` syntax is much more broad than ANSI standard, the problem you encounter can be reduced to multiple update the same row. With `UPDATE` you don't get any error or warning:

From **[`Let's deprecate UPDATE FROM!`](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2008/03/lets-deprecate-update-from/)** and **[`Deprecate UPDATE FROM and DELETE FROM`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/332437/deprecate-update-from-and-delete-from)** :

> **Correctness? Bah, who cares?**
>
> Well, most do. That’s why we test.
>
> If I mess up the join criteria in a SELECT query so that too many rows
>   from the second table match, I’ll see it as soon as I test, because I
>   get more rows back then expected. If I mess up the subquery criteria
>   in an ANSI standard UPDATE query in a similar way, I see it even
>   sooner, because SQL Server will return an error if the subquery
>   returns more than a single value. But with the proprietary UPDATE FROM
>   syntax, I can mess up the join and never notice – SQL Server will
>   happily update the same row over and over again if it matches more
>   than one row in the joined table, with only the result of the last of
>   those updates sticking. And there is no way of knowing which row that
>   will be, since that depends in the query execution plan that happens
>   to be chosen. A worst case scenario would be one where the execution
>   plan just happens to result in the expected outcome during all tests
>   on the single-processor development server – and then, after
>   deployment to the four-way dual-core production server, our precious
>   data suddenly hits the fan…

If you use for example `MERGE` you will get error indicating:

> **The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more
>   than once.** This happens when a target row matches more than one source
>   row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target
>   table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row
>   matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group
>   the source rows.

**So you need to be more carefull and check your code. I wish also to get error but as you see in connect link this won't happen.**

One way to avoid this is to use `UPDATE alias` so you are sure you use tables that take part in `FROM JOIN` and no other tables are involved.:

```
UPDATE A
SET COL_1=B.COL_1
FROM #TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN #TABLE_B B
   ON A.KEY_1=B.KEY_1
WHERE B.COL_2 IS NOT NULL
  AND A.COL_1=91216599;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL will allow a lot of stuff that probably does not make sense
Notice tableB is on both side of the on

```
select *  
from tableA
join tableB 
  on tableB.col1 = tableB.col1
```

SQL just checks syntax - it is up to you so write a statement that makes sense

There might be some case you really do want to do want a cross product type update

This is how I would write that statement
I line the table names up so it is easier to see

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
   SET A.COL_1 = B.COL_1
  FROM TABLE_A A
  JOIN TABLE_B B
        ON A.KEY_1 = B.KEY_1
       AND B.COL_2 IS NOT NULL
       AND A.COL_1 = 91216599 
       AND A.COL_1 <> B.COL_1
```

Comment: For me the easiest way to spot it is to use aliases in `UPDATE` like :`UPDATE A
SET COL_1=B.COL_1
FROM #TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN #TABLE_B B
   ON A.KEY_1=B.KEY_1
WHERE B.COL_2 IS NOT NULL
  AND A.COL_1=91216599;`