# How to UPDATE 1 row with multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

**EDIT:** This is just an simplified example, I know it seems really wrong, but thought this is the simpliest way to ask my question.

Let's say I have a `Person` and an 'Email' table. Each person can have 2 e-mails.

Here is a small example:

[image]

For some reason, we decide to extend our `Person` table with 2 columns: `FirstEmail`, and `SecondEmail`, so after an update, the results looks like something like this:

[image]

Can I `UPDATE` the table with a single statement? For example, I tried this, but it doesn't work (doesn't give error, only the `FirstEmail` is filled, the `SecondEmail` is `NULL`).

```
UPDATE Person
SET FirstEmail = CASE WHEN e.Type = 'FIRST' THEN e.Value ELSE FirstMail END,
    SecondMail = CASE WHEN e.Type = 'SECOND' THEN e.Value ELSE SecondMail END
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Email e ON (p.Id = e.PersonId);
```

And as I see `MERGE` can't work with multiple rows, because I get this error for a similar approach:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Comment: Whey would you denormalize your data here? Are you getting rid of the email table all together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: `"it doesn't work (doesn't give error...)"` [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32386372/5070879)

Comment: @scsimon of course it's just a simplified example to make my problem very easy to understand, what I'm actually need to do is more complex. So don't worry, I don't plan to do stupid thing like this :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following query should work for you.

```
UPDATE P
SET P.FirstEmail = F.Value, 
    P.SecondEmail= S.Value
FROM Person P
INNER JOIN EMAIL F ON F.PersonId=P.ID AND F.TYPE='FIRST'
INNER JOIN EMAIL S ON S.PersonId=P.ID AND S.TYPE='SECOND'
```

If you don't have both the emails for Person, in that case you can change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`

```
UPDATE P
SET P.FirstEmail = F.Value, 
    P.SecondEmail= S.Value
FROM Person P
LEFT JOIN EMAIL F ON F.PersonId=P.ID AND F.TYPE='FIRST'
LEFT JOIN EMAIL S ON S.PersonId=P.ID AND S.TYPE='SECOND'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using two subqueries the solution is trivial :

```
update Person set
       FirstEMail = (select top 1 Value from EMail where PersonId = Person.Id and Type = 'FIRST'),
       SecondEMail = (select top 1 Value from EMail where PersonId = Person.Id and Type = 'SECOND')
```

Comment: i would say add select top 1 with the subqueries for foolprrofness

Comment: @RAHULSR For foolproofness there should be explicit TOP + ORDER BY

Comment: @lad2025  you thnk thats necessory? since the where conditon is checking the exact match??

Comment: @RAHULSR With exact match there is no need for TOP 1

Comment: @lad2025 what if the same id has two FIRST Type val

Comment: id ->1 PersonID ->1 TYPE->FIRST,id->2 PersonID->2 Type -> FIRST

Comment: @RAHULSR Refering to your prev comment `since the where conditon is checking the exact match?? `

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your update attempt is that a row with a particular email is never "First" and "Second" at the same time (so either `FirstEmail` is updated or `SecondEmail` is, but never both).

A solution is using 2 joins, one for each email:

```
UPDATE P SET
    FirstEmail = E1.Value,
    SecondEmail = E2.Value
FROM
    Person AS P
    LEFT JOIN Email AS E1 ON
        E1.PersonID = P.ID AND
        E1.Type = 'First'
    LEFT JOIN Email AS E2 ON
        E2.PersonID = P.ID AND
        E2.Type = 'Second'
```