# When an UPDATE statement has access to multiple values, which one does it choose?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I didn't think this code would work, and now that is seems to be working I'm worried that it might not always work:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Dates

; WITH Dates
    AS (
        SELECT    CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS DATE) AS CDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT    DATEADD(dd, 1, CDate) AS CDate
            FROM Dates
                WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, CDate) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
        )

SELECT    d.CDate
        , d.CDate AS BDate
    INTO #Dates
        FROM Dates d
            OPTION (MAXRECURSION 400)

; WITH BDate
    AS (
        SELECT    CDate
            FROM #Dates d
                WHERE CDate NOT IN ('2018-01-01', '2018-01-15', '2018-02-19') -- New Years, MLK Day, Presidents Day
                        AND DATEPART(dw, d.CDate) NOT IN (1,7)

        )

UPDATE d
    SET d.BDate = b.CDate
        FROM #Dates d
            JOIN BDate b
                ON d.CDate <= b.CDate

SELECT * FROM #Dates
```

What I don't understand is how it knows which value to choose for the UPDATE statement. If we choose a random date like January 24th, a SELECT statement would give us multiple values (since that's a Wednesday and we're avoiding weekends, that list would include January 24th, 25th and 26th, and then jump to 29th, 30th, 31st, etc.). So why is it choosing the one I actually want (the minimum value that meets the criteria)? It won't let me use ORDER BY to force the order, of course.

Normally I would write my code more like this:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Dates

    ; WITH Dates
        AS (
            SELECT    CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS DATE) AS CDate
            UNION ALL
            SELECT    DATEADD(dd, 1, CDate) AS CDate
                FROM Dates
                    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, CDate) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
            )

    SELECT    d.CDate
            , d.CDate AS BDate
        INTO #Dates
            FROM Dates d
                OPTION (MAXRECURSION 400)

    ; WITH BDate
        AS (
            SELECT    CDate
                FROM #Dates d
                    WHERE CDate NOT IN ('2018-01-01', '2018-01-15', '2018-02-19') -- New Years, MLK Day, Presidents Day
                            AND DATEPART(dw, d.CDate) NOT IN (1,7)
            )

    , BDMin
        AS (
            SELECT    d.CDate
                    , MIN(b.CDate) AS BDate
                FROM #Dates d
                    JOIN BDate b
                        ON d.CDate <= b.CDate
                    GROUP BY d.CDate
            )

    UPDATE d
        SET d.BDate = b.BDate
            FROM #Dates d
                JOIN BDMin b
                    ON d.CDate = b.CDate

    SELECT * FROM #Dates
```

It certainly seems safer, but now I'm wondering if it's necessary.

Comment: Most databases will comply when there isn't a 1 to 1 relationship between the row to be updated and the updated value. SQL Server won't comply but it won't be deterministic also, so you should always **make sure that this doesn't happen**.

Comment: Intuitively, the results will be arbitrary. I've written what I think is a [simpler test](http://rextester.com/NLYAC44937), and while I did get the exact same results each run on multiple test environments, I still feel like this is arbitrary (mainly because I can't seem to find any logic in the result). I've also tested on [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=55a7bc87f83ee147688fa7b9fc027dc1) and my own sql server. Good question though, it will be interesting to see it answered by a real SQL Server expert.

Comment: I think what you did is solid.  TSQL will just decide on one.  I typically repeats but is not guaranteed.

Comment: Good answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385665/how-is-this-script-updating-table-when-using-left-joins/32386372#32386372