# Which row is used to update parent table with value from joined table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've had a use-case that requires me to retro-populate a table with a value from the first row (in order of insert) of a joined table.

I've written this simple query:

```
UPDATE parent
SET parent.FirstChildField = child.Field
FROM Parents parent
INNER JOIN Children AS child
ON child.parentId = parent.Id
```

Does this query update the FirstChildField with the value of Field from the FIRST row of joined children, or the LAST? The existing db uses Guids as primary keys.

Comment: How do you define first or last? SQL Server doesn't have any concept of which row was inserted first, unless you have some other signal (like an IDENTITY column, which is not 100% reliable, or a datetime column, which can potentially be altered). So if you want a specific choice to be made, you need to be able to tell SQL Server explicitly how to determine which row you mean. As is, the definition here is that SQL Server will choose an **arbitrary** row. That choice may seem constant in small sample sizes, but I can assure you that it can change.

Comment: There is no `First` and `Last` in a table. You have to specify the ordering with an `ORDER BY` clause in your query. If there is no field on which to order, then I'm afraid you are sunk.

Comment: [How is this script updating table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32386372/5070879)

Comment: @lad2025 Thank you for that link. That's terrible behavior. Deleting my comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) explicitly warns about this:

> Use caution when specifying the FROM clause to provide the criteria
>   for the update operation. The results of an UPDATE statement are
>   undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not
>   specified in such a way that only one value is available for each
>   column occurrence that is updated, that is if the UPDATE statement is
>   not deterministic.

I think the documentation is a wee bit harsh.  The results are indeterminate, but the the resulting value should come from one of rows, so the result is not completed undefined.

There is no particular row that it comes from.  There is no guarantee that the same update on the same data on the same system will produce the same results.

You can control which gets updated using `apply`:

```
UPDATE p
    SET FirstChildField = c.Field
FROM Parents p CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) c.*
      FROM Children c
      WHERE c.parentId = p.Id
      ORDER BY ?
     ) c;
```

The `?` is for the column that determines which row you want to use for the `update`.

Comment: Seems like it would have been easier to throw an error then it was to add this to the documentation. I had no idea SQL Server did this.

Comment: Thanks Gordon that's very helpful.