# T-SQL String Replace is Not Locking - Last Update Wins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, locking

I have the following stored procedure, which is intended to iterate through a list of strings, which contains several substrings of the form `prefix.bucketName`. I want to iterate through each string and each bucket name, and replace the old prefix with a new prefix, but keep the same bucket name.

To give an example, consider this original string:

`"(OldPrefix.BucketA)(OldPrefix.BucketB)"`

So for example I would like to get:

`"(NewPrefix.BucketA)(NewPrefix.BucketB)"`

What I *actually* get is this:

`"(OldPrefix.BucketA)(NewPrefix.BucketB)"`

So, in general, only one of the prefixes get updated, and it is not predictable which one. Based on some investigation I have done, it appears that both replacements actually work, but only the last one is actually saved. It seems like SQL should be locking this column but instead, both are read at the same time, the replace is applied, and then both are written, leaving the last write as what shows in the column.

Here is the query - All variable names have been changed for privacy - Some error handling and data validation code was left out for brevity:

```
DECLARE @PrefixID INT                   = 1478,
DECLARE @PrefixName_OLD NVARCHAR(50)    = 'OldPrefix',
DECLARE @PrefixName_NEW NVARCHAR(50)    = 'NewPrefix'

BEGIN TRAN 
    -- Code to rename the section itself here not shown for brevity

    UPDATE 
        dbo.Component 
    SET
        AString= REPLACE(AString,'('+@Prefix_OLD+'.'+b.BucketName+')', '('+@PrefixName_NEW+'.'+b.BucketName+')'),
    FROM
        dbo.Component sc
    JOIN
        dbo.ComponentBucketFilterInString  fis
    ON
        sc.ComponentID = fis.ComponentID
    JOIN
        dbo.Buckets b
    ON
        fis.BucketID = b.BucketID   
    WHERE
        b.PrefixID = @PrefixID
COMMIT
RETURN 1
```

When I write the same query using a while loop, it performs as expected:

```
DECLARE @BucketsToUpdate TABLE 
(
    BucketID INT,
    BucketName VARCHAR(256)
)

INSERT INTO @BucketsToUpdate
SELECT BucketID, BucketName
FROM Buckets WHERE PrefixID = @PrefixID

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @BucketsToUpdate)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @currentBucketID INT,
            @currentBucketName VARCHAR(256)
    SELECT TOP 1 @currentBucketID = bucketID, @currentBucketName = bucketName FROM @BucketsToUpdate 
    UPDATE 
            dbo.Component 
        SET
            AString = REPLACE(AString,'('+@PrefixName_OLD+'.'+@currentBucketName+')', '('+@PrefixName_NEW+'.'+@currentBucketName+')')
        FROM
            dbo.Component  sc
        JOIN
            dbo.ComponentBucketFilterInString  fis
        ON
            sc.ComponentID = fis.ComponentID
        WHERE fis.BucketID = @currentBucketID
    DELETE FROM @BucketsToUpdate WHERE BucketID = @currentBucketID
END
```

Why does the first version fail? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please post sample data http://dbfiddle.uk The problem is most likely [UPDATE FROM JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385665/how-is-this-script-updating-table-when-using-left-joins/32386372#32386372) when multiple rows are matching the same row to update you got undefined behaviour - **last update wins**

Comment: Will do, allow me a moment.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda This should give you what you need https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=432733dbb128cb658b71018494065e2a

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda I am not certain, but based on your comment it appears that what you have posted is the only explanation based on what I am experiencing. Care to leave that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is "undefined" behavior when there is more than single match possible for `UPDATE FROM JOIN`.

In order to make your update possible you should run it multiple times updating one pair of values at a time as you proposed in your second code demo.

Related: [How is this script updating table when using LEFT JOINs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385665/how-is-this-script-updating-table-when-using-left-joins/32386372#32386372) and [Let’s deprecate UPDATE FROM!](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2008/03/lets-deprecate-update-from/):

> **SQL Server will happily update the same row over and over again if it matches more than one row in the joined table, >>with only the result of the last of those updates sticking<<.**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are making the whole process so complex. May be I am not clearly understanding the requirement. As per my understanding, you are looking to update only Prefix part for column 'AString' in the table dbo.Component. Current value for example is-

```
(OldPrefix.BucketA)(OldPrefix.BucketB)
```

You wants to update the value as-

```
(NewPrefix.BucketA)(NewPrefix.BucketB)
```

Am I right? If yes, you can update all records with a simple Update script as below-

```
DECLARE @PrefixID INT                   = 1478
DECLARE @PrefixName_OLD NVARCHAR(50)    = 'OldPrefix'
DECLARE @PrefixName_NEW NVARCHAR(50)    = 'NewPrefix'

UPDATE  Component 
SET AString= REPLACE(AString,@PrefixName_OLD,@PrefixName_NEW)
```

Comment: Well, I have sinmplified the code and example given to make the problem easier to understand, but in reality it is not so simple. There is a lot of special syntax in these strings, and I need to be careful not to replace instances of the prefix which are not immediately followed by the bucketname.

Comment: Just show some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: I cannot be too specific with this data, as it is owned by my company. Just trust when I say that for reasons I cannot specify, I need to do this replacement in a manner similar to how I have specified.

Comment: So what issue you are facing using my Simple Update script?